# Creating a single regex rather than a nested statement

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I want to do the following match:

> match if `MBzz` is in the string but not if `[Rr][Ee][Ff]` is in the string

So the following should match:

- klasdlkMBzzsdld
- MBzz

And the following should not match:

- RefmmmmMBzzmmmmm
- MBzzmmmmmmREFmmmm

etc.

For now, I am doing this terrible hack:

```
def mySearch(val):
    if (re.compile('MBab').search(val) is not None) and \
       (re.compile('[Rr][Ee][Ff]').search(val) is None):
        return re.compile('MBab').search(val).group()
    return None
```

However, I feel that for something that is as simple as this, I should be able to accomplish this as a one liner.

Comment: For some reason, my computer did an autocorrect for regex to reggae

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following regex with modifier `i` for ignoring the case :

```
^(?:(?!ref).)*(?=MBzz)(?:(?!ref).)*$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cS1oF3/1)

```
regex=re.compile(r'^[^ref]*(?=MBzz)[^ref]*$',re.I|re.MULTILINE)
```

The positive look behind `(?=MBzz)` will ensure your regex engine that your string contains `MBzz` and following negative look behind `(?:(?!ref).)*` will match any thing except `ref`.

And if you want yo consider the case for `MBzz` you can use following regex without ignore case modifier :

```
^(?:(?![rR][eE][fF]).)*(?=MBzz)(?:(?![rR][eE][fF]).)*$
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Its nearly exactly what I want, except that I *do* want to match the case for `MBzz`. But the positive and negative look behinds look very interesting. Ill definitely take a look at them.